# Windows 10 batch file: How to get rid of flashing input marker?

Tags: windows-10, batch

I've been making a little 'loading' program with batch (show at the bottom) and when I test it there is that annoying little blinking marker that indicates where to type in the `cmd`. However, you can't type anything so it is useless. It really takes away from it and it's all I can see.

Is there any way to stop the input marker from blinking?
Or, even better, stop it altogether?

My code is:

```
@echo off
title Loading...
:start
@echo .
PING localhost -n 2 >NUL
cls
@echo ..
PING localhost -n 2 >NUL
cls
@echo ...
PING localhost -n 2 >NUL
cls
@echo
cls
goto start
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution at https://stackoverflow.com/a/15229150/4609258 might be an approach. It does't remove the cursor, but keeps it at a better position by sending carriage return.